# how to solve TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.allowFontScaling')

Tags: react-native, expo

I upgraded expo and was using react-native-star-rating and I'm getting:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.allowFontScaling')
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

I saw something about a patch to this but I dont know how I do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to node_modules/react-native-button/Button.js

and add

```
import {TextPropTypes} from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'
```

Change `'static propTypes'` to

```
static propTypes = {
...
allowFontScaling: TextPropTypes.allowFontScaling,
...
style: TextPropTypes.style
styleDisabled: TextPropTypes.style,
...
};
```

Obviously, you will have to npm install deprecated-react-native-prop-types first then do the above stated things. Hope it helps

Comment: This is the correct, but you will then need to do this every time you install this package. What you want to do is either upgrade that package to one that has this change already, or if it's not well maintained you will need to fork it and do this change there, then update your `package.json` to reference your fixed fork instead.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter for now, you can use react-native-patch-package to avoid this.

Comment: @hugger Yup, that'll work as well if that's your preference.